# NEST: How to match for documents with one of element as multi-values, finding any of the field matching to filter value

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

```
    var results = client.MultiSearch(a => a
                                    .Search<StockBaseEntity>(s => s
                                      .Type("item")
                                      .Take(3)
                                           .Query(qq =>
                                                  qq.Filtered(ft => ft
                                                      .Filter(f => f
                                                          .Bool(bb => bb.Must(ms =>
{
          FilterInputs mustfilters;
          mustfilters &= ms.Terms("cityId", filterInputs.cities);
}
```

filterInputs.cities is string array. (string[])

I have not mentioned the full multi search query here.

But it returns (Suppose cities are 1,2,3,4):

1. If document element has cityId 1 AND filterInputs.cities has 1,
   this record is returned.
2. If document element has cityId 3 AND
   filterInputs.cities has 1,3 this record is returned.
3. If document
   element has cityId 4 AND filterInputs.cities has 1,2 this record is
   returned.

Basically ms.Terms matches for any particular city in filterInputs.cities and returns the document.

We have changed the document. Now we have "cities" instead of "cityId". "cities" can have multiple comma separated cityIds.
So, new behavior should be:

1. If document element has cities 1 AND filterInputs.cities has 1, this record is returned.
2. If document element has cities 3,4 AND filterInputs.cities has 1,3 this record is returned.
3. If document element has cites 1,2,4 AND filterInputs.cities has 1,2 this record is returned.
4. If document element has cites 1,2 AND filterInputs.cities has 3,4 this record is NOT returned.

Here also it should match for any occurrence or else return false. How should i modify the nest query?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to analyze the field "cities" such that eventually it contains an array of city ids. Then all the scenarios that you've mentioned will work. You can use [Pattern Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html) for this.